# How to scrap content on leaflet map for all pops-up with python

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, leaflet, popup

I am trying to extract text from all pop-up which are in this leaflet-map and export as csv file with pandas. To do so, i wrote a code focus on CSS selector, but it seems to run without doing anything.

Does someone know, what's wrong ?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/XXXXX/PycharmProjects/carte_pénurie_essence/geckodriver 2")
driver.get('https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/w/')
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    #(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#didomi-notice-agree-button>span"))).click()  # Accept the cookie button

while (True):
    try:
        Nom_entreprise = [name.text for name in
                 driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#map > div.leaflet-map-pane > div.leaflet-objects-pane > div.leaflet-popup-pane > div > "
                                                       "div.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper > div > div > div.brand_station_container > div.brand_container")]
        Nom_entreprise_ville = [address.text for address in
                     driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#map > div.leaflet-map-pane > div.leaflet-objects-pane > div.leaflet-popup-pane > div "
                                                           "> div.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper > div > div > div.brand_station_container > div.station_name")]

        Address_gps = [city.text for city in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#map > div.leaflet-map-pane > div.leaflet-objects-pane "
                                                                                   "> div.leaflet-popup-pane > div > div.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper > div > div > div.brand_station_container > div.station_address")]
        print("je passe")
    except:
        print("Finito")
        break

df = pd.DataFrame({"Nom_entreprise": Nom_entreprise, "Nom_entreprise_ville": Nom_entreprise_ville,
                           "Address_gps": Address_gps})



print(df)

df.to_csv("stations_en_pénurie.csv")
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: maybe it sends popups data as JSON data in separated requests and maybe you could read it with request. OR maybe it has it as JSON data directly in HTML (in tag `<script>`)

Comment: maybe first run without `try/except` to see full error message

Comment: at the beginnig of HTML you should see `var station = ... `  and probably there are all information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need selenium's overheads for this job: it's perfectly doable with requests only. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

r = requests.get('https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/w/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
script_w_data = soup.select_one('''script:-soup-contains('var stations = [')''')
bad_json = script_w_data.text.split('var stations = [')[1].rsplit(']', 1)[0].strip()
good_data = json.loads('[' + bad_json + ']')
df = pd.json_normalize(good_data)
df.to_csv('stuffs_on_map.csv')
print(df)
```

Result in terminal (also saved as csv):

```
    id  lat lng brand   brand_icon_url  name    city    address status  missing_gas_types
0   1   45.957000   5.332850    Avia    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-avia-120x120.png   GARAGE VINCENT SAS  AMBéRIEU-EN-BUGEY   15 Avenue de la Libération, AMBéRIEU-EN-BUGEY, France   no-gas  [None]
1   5   45.755720   5.683340    Auchan  https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-auchan-120x120.png Auchan  BELLEY  Rue Mante, BELLEY, France   no-gas  [gasoil, e85, sp95]
2   6   45.758877   5.704204    Carrefour Market    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-carrefour-market-120x120.png   Carrefour Market    Belley  Z.A. de l'Ousson Ouest\n01300‎ Belley\nFrance   no-gas  [e10, sp98, diesel+, sp95]
3   7   45.822823   4.997240    Leclerc https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-leclerc-120x120.png    Leclerc Bourg-en-Bresse 01700‎ Beynost\nFrance  no-gas  [None]
4   9   46.218420   5.227670    Carrefour Market    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-carrefour-market-120x120.png   Carrefour Market    BOURG-EN-BRESSE 16 Avenue de Marboz, BOURG-EN-BRESSE, France    no-gas  [sp98]
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
3218    213498  49.000000   3.000000    Carrefour Market    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-carrefour-market-120x120.png   carrefour market    Bohain-en-Vermandois    87 rue de st quentin, Bohain-en-Vermandois, France  some-gas    [gasoil]
3219    213933  48.852566   2.466261    Avia    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-avia-120x120.png   Avia    Fontenay-sous-Bois  234 Avenue de la République\n94120 Fontenay-sous-Bois\nFrance   no-gas  [None]
3220    213935  43.208859   2.381277    Leclerc https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-leclerc-120x120.png    Leclerc Carcassonne 1–3 Avenue du Souvenir Français\n11000 Carcassonne\nFrance  some-gas    [gasoil, diesel+]
3221    213936  49.156439   1.352845    Total   https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-total-120x120.png  Total Energies Access   Eure    1bis Côte des Sables, 27600 Gaillon, France no-gas  [None]
3222    213938  43.253964   5.421295    Avia    https://penurie.mon-essence.fr/static/station/brandresources/icn-avia-120x120.png   Avia    Marseille   83A Boulevard du Redon\n13009 Marseille\nFrance no-gas  [None]
3223 rows × 10 columns
```

​Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also, Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And BeautifulSoup docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/